Multiprocessing and sourcing shell file for every subprocess
I am working on a code which aims to gather simulation commands and multiprocess them, sourcing a shell file for each subprocess before running a simulation command in the subprocess. For this I gather the commands in another function in a dictionary which is used by the functions below:
    def source_shell_script(self, script_path: str) -> dict:
        """
        Sources a shell script and updates the environment for each subprocess.
        """
        if not os.path.exists(script_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Script not found: {script_path}")
        
        # source the script and output environment variables
        command = f"bash -c 'source {script_path} && env'"
        
        try:
            # run the command and capture the output
            result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, check=True)
            # parse the environment variables from the command output
            env_vars = dict(
                line.split("=", 1) for line in result.stdout.splitlines() if "=" in line
            )
            return env_vars
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to source script: {script_path}. Error: {e}")

    def run_cmd(self, cmd_px: tuple) -> None:
        cmd, px_src_path = cmd_px
        try:
            # get environment variables
            env_vars = self.source_shell_script(px_src_path)
            print(f"Executing command: {cmd}")
            result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, env=env_vars, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
            print(f"Output: {result.stdout}")
            if result.returncode != 0:
                print(f"Error: {result.stderr}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to execute command: {cmd}. Error: {e}")

    def exec_sim(self) -> None:
        """
        Execute all simulations in parallel using multiprocessing.
        """
        # create a list of (command, px_src_path) tuples for each pixel configuration
        run_queue = [(cmd, self.sim_dict[px_key]["px_src_path"]) 
                    for px_key in self.sim_dict 
                    for cmd in self.sim_dict[px_key]["px_ddsim_cmds"]]
        
        num_workers = os.cpu_count()  # number of processes
        with multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers) as pool:
            pool.map(self.run_cmd, run_queue)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialize program
    eic_object = HandleEIC()
    eic_object.init_path_var()
    pixel_sizes = eic_object.setup_json()
    eic_object.pixel_sizes = pixel_sizes  
    os.chmod(eic_object.execution_path, 0o777)
    
    eic_object.setup_sim()
    print("Simulation dictionary:", eic_object.sim_dict)
    
    eic_object.exec_sim()

    # create backup for simulation
    eic_object.mk_sim_backup()

Instead of running properly, my program gets stuck and the console prints the commands:
Console output:
Simulation dictionary: {'2.0_0.1': {'px_epic_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic', 'px_compact_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/compact', 'px_ip6_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/epic_ip6_extended.xml', 'px_src_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic/install/bin/thisepic.sh', 'px_out_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px', 'px_ddsim_cmds': ['ddsim --inputFiles /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/genEvents/results/beamEffectsElectrons_20.hepmc --outputFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/output_20edm4hep.root --compactFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/epic_ip6_extended.xml -N 5']}, '0.1_0.1': {'px_epic_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/epic', 'px_compact_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/compact', 'px_ip6_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/epic_ip6_extended.xml', 'px_src_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/epic/install/bin/thisepic.sh', 'px_out_path': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px', 'px_ddsim_cmds': ['ddsim --inputFiles /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/genEvents/results/beamEffectsElectrons_20.hepmc --outputFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/output_20edm4hep.root --compactFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/epic_ip6_extended.xml -N 5']}}
Executing command: ddsim --inputFiles /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/genEvents/results/beamEffectsElectrons_20.hepmc --outputFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/output_20edm4hep.root --compactFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/0.1x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/epic_ip6_extended.xml -N 5
Executing command: ddsim --inputFiles /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/genEvents/results/beamEffectsElectrons_20.hepmc --outputFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/output_20edm4hep.root --compactFile /data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/2.0x0.1px/epic/install/share/epic/epic_ip6_extended.xml -N 5

Why is my code not running as expected? What am I doing wrong?

I don't know what exactly your shells scripts are supposed to do, but using the word "sourcing" is confusing at best, since it makes the reader believe that you try to source bash code, which - by its nature - can't be done in a Python program. You can at best created a bash child process and inside this, source some bash stuff. When we speak of sourcing, we refer to processing code inside the process space of the caller.

Since the command you're running in source_shell_script() is bash, it is at best reundant to run the subprocess with shell=True.  That wraps another level of shell around the shell you explicitly execute.  But this probably is not the source of your issue.

"Why is my code not running as expected?" -- how about telling us what you expect, and why?

What have you already done to troubleshoot?  For example, have you confirmed that source_shell_script() computes the wanted environment correctly?  Have you confirmed that run_cmd() works as desired when run directly instead of via a thread pool?  Do the simulation commands you are trying to execute work as intended when you run them directly from a shell?

It seems awfully roundabout to collect environment variables via a separate process, when you could instead just roll that into the command to run each simulation.  Especially (but not only) because you're already running the simulations with shell=True, which appears otherwise to be unneeded.

In general, btw, using string substitution to generate code evaluated by a shell is Here There Be Serious Security Vulnerabilities territory. Even if you're sourceing a file, if those files are human-vetted, it's far safer to use subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', 'source "$1" && env', 'bash', script_path], shell=False)

Another note: source is specifically a bash keyword; the sh equivalent is . (so instead of source filename, the POSIX-compliant equivalent is . filename)

Separately, env output isn't guaranteed to be line-oriented at all, because environment variables' values can and do contain newlines. It's much safer to represent lists of environment variables and values in NUL-delimited form, as a NUL -- unlike the newline -- is the only character that cannot exist in an environment variable's value.

Another note: Environment variables are inherited from the parent process, so if a file you sourced before starting your parent process sets all the necessary variables, child processes created by multiprocessing will already have those variables when they're created. If you're doing things right you should never need to have a shell between parent and child Python processes.

Kindly check now after these changes.
Changes:
1.The source_shell_script method sources the shell script and returns environment variables. These variables are passed into the subprocess.run call via the env parameter.
If the script is missing, a FileNotFoundError is raised. If sourcing fails, a RuntimeError is raised.
2.The run_cmd method now checks for the return code of the subprocess. If the command fails (result.returncode != 0), the error is printed using stderr. Otherwise, it prints the output using stdout.
If any exception occurs during the above process, it's caught and printed.

The exec_sim method collects the simulation commands and pixel source paths. It uses multiprocessing.Pool to execute the commands in parallel, with each worker running run_cmd.

4, The simulation dictionary holds the simulation details, including paths to the shell scripts and the commands to run. This (sim_dict) is assumed to be initialized in setup_json.

execution_path should exist and should have correct permissions (0o777)

Added more verbose logging (print) (to help trace command execution.
Check the output and confirm if the paths and commands are coect.


7.Test the script with a simplified example first. Ensure that the paths to the shell scripts (px_src_path) and the simulation commands (px_ddsim_cmds) are correct.
import os
import subprocess
import multiprocessing


class SimulationHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sim_dict = {}

    def get_path(self, *path_components):
        """Joins path components into a single file path."""
        return os.path.join(*path_components)

    def source_shell_script(self, *path_components) -> dict:
        """Sources a shell script and returns the environment variables as a dictionary."""
        script_path = self.get_path(*path_components)

        if not os.path.exists(script_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f'Script not found: {script_path}')

        command = ['bash', '-c', 'source "$1" && env', 'bash', script_path]
        try:
            result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, check=True)
            env_vars = dict(
                line.split('=', 1) for line in result.stdout.splitlines() if '=' in line
            )
            return env_vars
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f'Failed to source script: {script_path}. Error: {e}')

    def run_cmd(self, cmd_px: tuple) -> None:
        """Executes a command with environment variables sourced from a shell script."""
        cmd, script_dir, script_name = cmd_px
        try:
            env_vars = self.source_shell_script(script_dir, script_name)
            print(f'Executing command: {cmd}')
            result = subprocess.run(
                cmd.split(),
                env=env_vars,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                text=True,
            )
            print(f'Output: {result.stdout}')
            if result.returncode != 0:
                print(f'Error: {result.stderr}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Failed to execute command: {cmd}. Error: {e}')

    def exec_sim(self) -> None:
        """Executes all simulations in parallel using multiprocessing."""
        run_queue = [
            (cmd, self.sim_dict[px_key]['script_dir'], self.sim_dict[px_key]['script_name'])
            for px_key in self.sim_dict
            for cmd in self.sim_dict[px_key]['commands']
        ]

        num_workers = os.cpu_count()  # Number of processes
        with multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers) as pool:
            pool.map(self.run_cmd, run_queue)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = SimulationHandler()

    # Example simulation dictionary for demonstration
    handler.sim_dict = {
        'config_1': {
            'script_dir': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/config_1/epic/install/bin',
            'script_name': 'thisepic.sh',
            'commands': [
                'ddsim --inputFiles input1.hepmc --outputFile output1.root --compactFile epic_ip6_extended.xml -N 5'
            ],
        },
        'config_2': {
            'script_dir': '/data/user/Analysis_epic_new/simulations/simEvents/config_2/epic/install/bin',
            'script_name': 'thisepic.sh',
            'commands': [
                'ddsim --inputFiles input2.hepmc --outputFile output2.root --compactFile epic_ip6_extended.xml -N 5'
            ],
        },
    }

    # Execute simulations
    handler.exec_sim()

Edit:
Reasons for the unexpected behavior:

For focus and hover behavior, rasio-button like widgets behave differently. For eg.,
When hovered, a Radiobutton might display a different border or background color by default, depending on the platform and theme.
Your code hasn't given style for hover or focus effects, so the default behavior is being used.

You're setting bg="#292d2e" for both Radiobutton and Label, but the Radiobutton itself might override some parts of the style when hovered (like its default border or highlight background). These overrides could result in visual artifacts.

The default behavior of widgets like Radiobutton can vary slightly across platforms (Windows, macOS, Linux), leading to hover effects you might not expect: Some themes or window managers have hover effects enabled by default for interactive widgets like buttons and radiobuttons.



It is conceivable that this revised script works better than the OP's, but even if so (and you don't seem confident), this answer is unclear about the answer to the actual question, which is about what is wrong with the original script.

@JohnBollinger, Thanks for pointing out. Now I've edited my answers. I;ve added the reasons for errotic behavior

Using shell=True with bash -c makes no sense -- that means you're running sh -c 'bash -c ...', starting a copy of sh whose only job is to start bash. It's far more sensible to use shell=False and pass an explicit argument vector array.

Beyond that, this answer perpetuates bad security practices -- it's much safer to pass dynamic content out-of-band from code (in the environment variables or the shell's argument vector) so it can't be misinterpreted as syntax. I touched on what better practices look like in a comment on the question.

(And beyond that, env doesn't return its output in a safe-to-parse format; consider the command export evil=$'hello\nPATH=/uploads/malicious-directory' -- many versions of env will show PATH=/uploads/malicious-directory as a separate line in output, even though the only variable defined is named evil)

Thank you all. I read all the comments. To make safe-to-parse format, I've added the line command = ['bash', '-c', 'source "$1" && env', 'bash', script_path]. Kindly confirm if this will do. shell=true with bash -c I've modified. Assuming that the users' OS can be anything I've added a path_join function also. Feel free to comment, If I need to change anything else also.
